# really simple doubt regarding minimum value of a super simple function

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, graphing-functions

I don't have much to ask. Just wanted to know if it is actually possible to write out the minimum value of the function $f(x)=x^3$ whenever it is defined over $(1,10)$ (**open interval**).

You can choose any other function (this came to my mind first!). So I know that the range of it is $(1,1000)$ for the specified domain. So does 1 count as the minimum value or do we say that "minimum and maximum do not exist" ?

Comment: On that domain there is neither min nor max.

Comment: Note that, however, for $f(x)=x^2$ on $(-1,1)$ the max does not exist but the min does.

Comment: Simple question-- simple answer.  Nope.  There is no minimal value on such an open interval.  For any $w \in (1,10)$ you will always have $w > 1$ and $f(w)=w^3  > 1$.  And you will *always* be able to find a smaller $w'$ where $1 < w' < w$ and $1 < w'^3 = f(w') < w^3 = f(w)$.  So you can't ever find a *smallest* value.

Comment: "So does 1 count as the minimum value ...?"  No.  Because $1$ does not actually *exist* (on the open interval)....  However we can say that $1$ is a *lower bound* of the function on that interval.  But as it is a lower bound that is *never* actually achieved it can't actually be a *minimum* as a minimum must be a value that *is* achieved.  .... and for any value that *is* achieved (no matter how small) we can *always* find a smaller value that is also achieved we can't find any *smallest* value (that is actually achieved).

Comment: "You can choose any other function " ... but there could be a different answer for a different function.  If $g(x) = (x-3)^2$ on the open interval $(1,10)$ then you'll see that if $1 < x < 3$ then $(x-3)< 0$ and $g(x) = (x-3)^2 > 0$ and if $3<x<10$ then $(x-3) > 0$ and $g(x)=(x-3)^2> 0$ but at $x=3$ then $g(x) = 0$ and that is the minimum.  This is because a min is acheived somewhere between the endpoints. but for $f(x)=x^3$ it is not and as the endpoint are *not* evaluated.....

Comment: @fleablood you shouldve answered dude ! thanks a ton ! got it.